# Visual Studio 2008 - Ctrl+E,D no longer resets indents in code

Tags: visual-studio-2008

How do I re-enable this?  It happened after I imported a settings theme, which I wanted because it made the font colors much nicer.

In options, is there a way to re-enable Ctrl+E,D to fix the comments?

Comment: The default setting is Ctrl-K, Ctrl-D for formatting a document.  Ctrl-E,D must have been a custom setting for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Options > Environment > Keyboard

Scroll in the commands list until you find `Edit.FormatDocument`

Set the key shortcut you want.

Answer (score 1):

I've always used Ctrl-K, Ctrl-D, which is in Edit | Advanced | Format Document.

Tools | Options | Environment | Keyboard has all the options for custom mappings you could possibly want, except remapping your caps lock key :P

Answer (score 0):

10 year old question ... but I had this issue today in a new install of VS 2019 16.7 and found this thread.

I also found a slightly different solution:
From the same Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard dialog that others have mentioned, select the **Visual C# 2005** keyboard mapping scheme - this will enable Ctrl+E D (as well as others that old-timers might have hard-wired into their muscle memory like Ctrl+E C to comment a selection and Ctrl+E U to uncomment).  For me, the was a lot easier than re-mapping each command one at a time.